Pimcore read object entity

Im studying about pimcore and I'm trying to mapping import from a JSON file to a class. But the problem is, my import file has a JSON object and I don't know how to get the URL from it (image above). Can anyon help me
Get the image url from the json object that show in image

Does this help? How to extract and access data from JSON with PHP?
